# No dual boot menu

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows

I formatted all of my disk and installed Ubuntu on my computer. I immediately partitioned, from an Ubuntu live CD, my hard drive, creating an NTFS partition for for Windows. After successfully doing so, I went on to install windows 8.1. After I installed Windows 8 in the new partition and turned off my PC and turned it on again the option to chose which Operating system I wanted to use didn't appear, loading Windows like if Ubuntu didn't exist.

How can I have the option to chose which operating system I want to run or at least from which partition to boot from when I start my computer?

EVERYTHING IS OKAY WITH MY OPERATING SYSTEM

The only thing I need is for ubuntu to appear as an option on the boot menus

Comment: If you're using UEFI you should be able to choose the boot menu entry from the BIOS boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

1. boot your ubuntu live cd
2. try ubuntu
3. connect to internet
4. run on terminal

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair

boot-repair

Answer (score 0):

Download `boot repair disk` from [**here**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/files/)
.Make the disk bootable through usb using the software `unetbootin` on windows.Once the disk booted up click on the **recommended repair** option.It update and reinstall the grub.now you have two os's on the boot menu.

Comment: Well, I do boot from my disk, I boot windows 8.1 from my disk. The problem is that I can't see the ubuntu option when loading. It loads windows automatically without asking me

Comment: If I install GRUB, will it appear at the beginning after the BIOS to make me choose an operating system?

Comment: yes,if you install grub,it will appears at the begining and make you to choose the operating system.Did you able to boot into windows?Then you can try `EasyBCD`.Download and install easybcd on your windows,under linux tab make entry for your ubuntu partition and also create entry for your windows partition.It would help you.

Answer (score 0):

1st. Make sure that ubuntu still exists on your hard drive. It is a very very common mistake to overwrite the existing partition when installing a newer one.

If thats not the case , you can use Avinash's advice and try recovering/repairing the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't done anything on Ubuntu yet you can reinstall it without fearing data loss. In the setup use the **"Something else"** option to set up exactly the partition you created/like the first setup did. Now make sure you choose the root drive with the **MBR** for the bootloader installation. This means *NO* partition like `/dev/sda1` but `/dev/sda`! This will overwrite the link to the bootloader of windows but grub will list an option for starting windows later. If you want to restore the previous bootloader you can use a windows recovery cd/dvd.
Maybe not the first guess but I made the mistake to choose a partition before...

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding this is an issue of there not being any entries for Ubuntu. Does it even give you a GRUB boot menu with Windows listed on it?

Following Invoker's suggestions, you should probably check that the Ubuntu partition even exists on the disk using Windows' Disk Management tool.